# fetching text between two specific elements in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am working on a nodejs project in which I need to parse .html file
to obtain everything between  elements and convert them to .csv

something like this:

```
</tr><tr style="color:#333333;background-color:White;">                                                           
                    <td>2016-04-28</td><td>RLYUDP-DP</td><td>RELIANCE FIXED HORIZON FUND XXX SERIES 18-- DIVIDEND PAYOUT</td><
F204KB1254</td><td>10.0000</td><td>KARVY</td>                                                                                     
            </tr><tr style="color:#333333;background-color:White;">                                                           
                    <td>2016-04-28</td><td>RLYUGP-GR</td><td>RELIANCE FIXED HORIZON FUND XXX SERIES 18- GROWTH</td><td>YUGP</t
</td><td>10.0000</td><td>KARVY</td>                                                                                               
            </tr><tr style="color:#333333;background-color:White;">                                                           
                    <td>2016-04-28</td><td>UTCXDP-DP</td><td>UTI-CAPITAL PROTECTION ORIENTED SCHEME - SERIES VII - IV (1278 DA
D PLAN</td><td>CXDP</td><td>N</td><td>INF789FC1691</td><td>10.0000</td><td>KARVY</td>                                             
            </tr><tr style="color:#333333;background-color:White;">                                                           
                    <td>2016-04-28</td><td>UTCXGP-GR</td><td>UTI-CAPITAL PROTECTION ORIENTED SCHEME - SERIES VII - IV (1278 DA
PLAN</td><td>CXGP</td><td>Z</td><td>INF789FC1709</td><td>10.0000</td><td>KARVY</td>                                               
            </tr><tr style="color:#333333;background-color:White;">                                                           
                    <td>2016-04-28</td><td>UTXBAD-DP</td><td>UTI FIXED TERM INCOME FUND SERIES XXIV - XII (1099 DAYS) - ANNUAL
/td><td>N</td><td>INF789FC1782</td><td>10.0000</td><td>KARVY</td>                                                                 
            </tr><tr style="color:#333333;background-color:White;">                                                           
                    <td>2016-04-28</td><td>UTXBFD-DP</td><td>UTI FIXED TERM INCOME FUND SERIES XXIV - XII (1099 DAYS) - FLEXI 
td><td>N</td><td>INF789FC1766</td><td>10.0000</td><td>KARVY</td>                                                                  
            </tr><tr style="color:#333333;background-color:White;">                                                           
                    <td>2016-04-28</td><td>UTXBGP-GR</td><td>UTI FIXED TERM INCOME FUND SERIES XXIV - XII (1099 DAYS) - GROWTH
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have this sort of html snippet. I managed to form it by combining some of the sample `tr` tags you provided in the question. Let's also suppose that this snippet is in a file named `table.html`.

```html
<tbody>
  <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:White;">
    <td>2016-04-28</td>
    <td>RLYUDP-DP</td>
    <td>RELIANCE FIXED HORIZON FUND XXX SERIES 18-- DIVIDEND PAYOUT</td>
    <td>F204KB1254</td>
    <td>10.0000</td>
    <td>KARVY</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:White;">
    <td>2016-04-28</td>
    <td>RLYUGP-GR</td>
    <td>RELIANCE FIXED HORIZON FUND XXX SERIES 18- GROWTH</td>
    <td>YUGP</td>
    <td>10.0000</td>
    <td>KARVY</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:White;">
    <td>2016-04-28</td>
    <td>UTCXDP-DP</td>
    <td>UTI-CAPITAL PROTECTION ORIENTED SCHEME - SERIES VII - IV 1278 DAD PLAN</td>
    <td>CXDP</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>INF789FC1691</td>
    <td>10.0000</td>
    <td>KARVY</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:White;">
    <td>2016-04-28</td>
    <td>UTCXGP-GR</td>
    <td>UTI-CAPITAL PROTECTION ORIENTED SCHEME - SERIES VII - IV 1278 DAPLAN</td>
    <td>CXGP</td>
    <td>Z</td>
    <td>INF789FC1709</td>
    <td>10.0000</td>
    <td>KARVY</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:White;">
    <td>2016-04-28</td>
    <td>UTXBAD-DP</td>
    <td>UTI FIXED TERM INCOME FUND SERIES XXIV - XII (1099 DAYS) - ANNUAL</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>INF789FC1782</td>
    <td>10.0000</td>
    <td>KARVY</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The nodejs code that turns this file into a csv formatted string is as follows:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var parse = require('xml-parser');
var xml = fs.readFileSync('table.html', 'utf8');

var obj = parse(xml);

var data = [];
obj.root.children.forEach(function(tr) {
    data.push(tr.children.map(function(td) {
        return td.content;
    }).join(','));
});
data = data.join('\r\n');

console.log(data);
```

The output of `console.log` is:

`2016-04-28,RLYUDP-DP,RELIANCE FIXED HORIZON FUND XXX SERIES 18-- DIVIDEND PAYOUT,F204KB1254,10.0000,KARVY
2016-04-28,RLYUGP-GR,RELIANCE FIXED HORIZON FUND XXX SERIES 18- GROWTH,YUGP,10.0000,KARVY
2016-04-28,UTCXDP-DP,UTI-CAPITAL PROTECTION ORIENTED SCHEME - SERIES VII - IV 1278 DAD PLAN,CXDP,N,INF789FC1691,10.0000,KARVY
2016-04-28,UTCXGP-GR,UTI-CAPITAL PROTECTION ORIENTED SCHEME - SERIES VII - IV 1278 DAPLAN,CXGP,Z,INF789FC1709,10.0000,KARVY
2016-04-28,UTXBAD-DP,UTI FIXED TERM INCOME FUND SERIES XXIV - XII (1099 DAYS) - ANNUAL,N,INF789FC1782,10.0000,KARVY`

You will need to install [xml-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-parser) npm package for the code to run.

Please note that the csv might not be valid if the `td` content contains comma characters or line-feeds. You may need to escape those characters ore use a proper npm csv module.

**EDIT**

Considering that you cannot install `xml-parser` package, I propose a workaround. Go to the package source code on [github](https://github.com/segmentio/xml-parser/blob/master/index.js#L22-167) and copy the highlighted function `parse`. Paste the function code directly on your js file and remove the `require('xml-parser')` dependency.

Comment: your method seems promising..but can you help me installing xml-parser on Windows
I tried using npm install xml-parser on cmd
but that does not work (there's sth loading and nothing after that )

Comment: that is weird. try running cmd as administrator.

Comment: npm isn't installing xml-parser 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936873/npm-not-working-in-windows?

can we do it without xml-parser?

Comment: i tried adding the code to the function
but there was an error ...debug not defined
so I coped debug's source code and then there was an error

ms not defined ...what to do?

Comment: Just delete all debug statements.