# npm not working in windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I installed node.js along with npm 
when in the winodws command prompt  I enter

```
npm -v
```

it returns 2.15.1
but when I try to install a package like:

```
npm install xml-parser
```

I see something loading and nothing  after that.

What's going  wrong?

Comment: Thats a really old npm version, make sure you're downloading the latest node.

Comment: I installed node 6.0.0 with npm 3.8.6
But now when I try to install a package..cmd hangs showing this:

loadRequetedDep -> get -: #######------------------ :

OR

normalizeTree->header:-----------------------------------:

and nothing after that..any help?

Comment: NPM takes time, give it a few minutes

Comment: Sometimes it has to compile native code

Comment: not working! ..it is stuck

Comment: Try running `npm --verbose install xml-parser` to see if you get any more helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried checking :
node --version

Comment: Please give a full explanation.